# Vimeo embedded video page displays a black box partially covering the video frame when orientation changes on the iPad

Tags: ipad, video, vimeo

The Vimeo videos that we have embedded in a WP website video page display and play just fine in all browsers but on the iPad a blackbox appears when changing orientation. It partially overlaps the video frame that stays visible below. It appears to be a new instance of the embedded video with no enough bandwidth to display the image...Any ideas on how to prevent this from happening?